# Null Pointer Exception in InputConnection.finishComposingText() method

Tags: android

I am getting a NPE in inputmethod.InputConnection.finishComposingText(),
The Log message is as follows:

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke interface method 'boolean android.view.inputmethod.InputConnection.finishComposingText()' on a null object reference
        at android.view.inputmethod.InputConnectionWrapper.finishComposingText(InputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper.executeMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:362)
        at com.android.internal.view.IInputConnectionWrapper$MyHandler.handleMessage(IInputConnectionWrapper.java:78)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:904)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:699)
```

I am facing it in Android 5 but works fine in Android .

The error is not specifying any line of code from my code just telling some code lines from library.

I am facing it whenever I press back button to move from one activity to main activity. And yes also other activity contains EditText.

I removed all the instances of softKeyboard, I thought it was due to that

It will be great if someone can help me thanks in advance

Comment: The linked question says that the bug has been fixed in AS 3.1.1. I am using 3.1.2 and still getting the NullPointer error.

Comment: I am using 3.1.3 AS but not receiving this error. the below solution worked like a charm I never see this error ever again

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Go to `Edit configuration settings -> Profiling -> Enable advanced profiling`
this will prevent `EditText` from crashing.

Comment: Thanks for helping and saving my time. It worked!

Comment: I had to disable advanced profiling to fix this issue.

Comment: Relevant ticket in Google Issue tracker if anyone's interested: https://issuetracker.google.com/issues/77764953

Comment: Disabling advanced profiling is solved the issue. Actually the issue is solved and will be available from Android Studio 3.2